# With gradle 6.7 I am not able to aggregate test reports of subprojects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to apply the "Example 4. Creating a unit test report for subprojects" of the gradle documentation see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_reporting)

```
Root project name: root
group name: root.group.name
version: 1.0.0
```

My project has the following structure:

```
/A/build.gradle
/B/build.gradle
/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/root.java-conventions.gradle
/build.gradle
```

root.java-conventions.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

// Disable the test report for the individual test task
test {
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

// Share the test report data to be aggregated for the whole project
configurations {
    binaryTestResultsElements {
        canBeResolved = false
        canBeConsumed = true
        attributes {
            attribute(Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Category, Category.DOCUMENTATION))
            attribute(DocsType.DOCS_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(DocsType, 'test-report-data'))
        }
        outgoing.artifact(test.binaryResultsDirectory)
    }
}
```

in build.gradle of the root project:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the groovy Plugin to add support for Groovy.
    id 'groovy'

    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'java-library'
}

configurations {
    testReportData {
        canBeResolved = true
        canBeConsumed = false
        attributes {
            attribute(Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Category, Category.DOCUMENTATION))
            attribute(DocsType.DOCS_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(DocsType, 'test-report-data'))
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testReportData project(":A")
    testReportData project(":B")
}

tasks.register('testReport', TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
    // Use test results from testReportData configuration
    testResultDirs.from(configurations.testReportData)
}
```

I think I am properly applying the example.

However, gradle outputs the following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':testReport'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':testReportData'.
> Could not resolve project :A.
        Required by:
project :
> No matching variant of project :A was found. The consumer was configured to find documentation of type 'test-report-data' but:
- Variant 'apiElements' capability root.group.name:A:1.0.0:
- Incompatible because this component declares a library and the consumer needed documentation
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about the documentation type (required documentation of type 'test-report-data')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' capability root.group.name:A:1.0.0:
- Incompatible because this component declares a library and the consumer needed documentation
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about the documentation type (required documentation of type 'test-report-data')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' capability root.group.name:A:1.0.0 declares documentation:
- Incompatible because this component declares sources and the consumer needed documentation of type 'test-report-data'
```

Any idea of why this is failing for me?